# Android studio doesn't start on windows Error invoking main method

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

Android Studio is not starting.when I click to open it gives me below error.Any suggestion for error.
I have already set the environment variable[ANDROID_HOME,JAVA_HOME,JDK_HOME].

[image]

Comment: Solved the problem by uninstaling and reinstalling jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling JDK.

Answer (score 1):

If idea.properties file is run inside notepad, make sure the file have file name of "idea" only instead of "idea.properties". It is a "idea" file with extension of ".properties".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened because the `idea.properties` file in the bin directory was missing. I simply restored it with a backup version I had and Android Studio worked again. I was running on Windows 64 bit with Android Studio version 2.2.1.

I think the file went missing in the first place because I modified the file and when Android Studio was updating itself to the latest version, it detected the modified file and something went wrong with the update process and deleted the file.

Answer (score 0):

First check idea.properties file in the bin directory if it's missing restore it with a backup.
if this didn't work then 
you can uninstall and reinstall JDK

I hope any one of this work for you.

If i am wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I edited the file with Notepad and it saved the file as idea.properties.txt instead of idea.properties. Renaming solved the issue.

As the Windows hide extension by default, it would be good to go to View menu of File Explorer and enable "File name extensions"

Answer (score 0):

In case it may be helpful to anyone landing on this page, I wanted to report that I fixed this by restarting my PC.

I first kept having trouble building an app, then I closed Android Studio. I got this error repeatedly when I tried to start AS again.